# Echo\ write variable as text and not as variable bat

Tags: variables, batch-file, text

I have a bit of a pridicument where I want to echo %USERNAME% not as a variable but as the text "% U S E R N A M E %" (without the spaces) how can I achive this ussing batch script?

```
Echo IF ^"%USERNAME%^"==^"BLABLA^" GOTO BLABLA >> test.txt
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within a `cmd` file (which is the most likely case since this is a *programming* Q&A site), you can simply double the `%` markers as they turn into a single `%` marker in the output.

Examine the following transcript (from Windows 7):

[image]

You can see that the double-`%` markers have been transformed into single `%` characters and the result is a well formed expression in the created file.

Comment: Doubling percents on the command line as shown does not work! Doubling quotes only works within a batch file. Escaping percent on command line only appears to work. Your example actually looks for variable named `xyzzy^`, and when not found, prints the original text with carets removed. It will fail if earlier you define `set "xyzzy^=causeFailure"`

Comment: All those examples were copied directly from the command line, so they do indeed work.

Comment: When I use `echo ^"%%xyzzy%%^"` on the Windows 7 command line, the result I get is `"%plugh%"`. I've done similar experiments on XP and Vista in the past, and double percents never worked for me on the command line.

Comment: Dbenham, then there's something different about your environment, I would suggest, they were all performed on Win7. I'll do some further checks today.

Comment: Yes, please double check on your end. I retested and got `"%plugh%"` on two Win 7 machines and one XP machine. I've also seen multiple posts from jeb describing the behavior as I specified, never anything like you are reporting with double percents on the command line.

Comment: @dbenham, you may be right, I tested on a different Win7 box this morning and got the same results as you. Then I went back to the original Win7 box and still got the same results. I'm certain I copied and pasted as-is but I may be incorrect. In any case, I've modified the answer to restrict it to the cmd-file solution since command-line stuff isn't really programming.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set xyzzy=plugh
echo DO you want ""%xyzzy%" or "%%xyzzy%%" ?
ECHO the forms ^"%xyzzy%^" and ^"^%xyzzy^%^" don't work WITHIN a .bat (but do from the prompt)
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: +1, but caret does not actually escape percent on command line. Instead, the processor looks for variable named `xyzzy^`, and preserves the original text (without carets) when not found. Only one caret is needed, and it could be placed anywhere between the percents. But if variable with that name exists, then it fails. For example `set "xyzzy^=value"` will cause failure of `%xyzzy^%` (it expands).

Comment: @dbenham - I'd theorise a matter of heritage; `%` escaping `%` being ~MSDOS2 vintage which needed to be maintained. The `^` as a general-purpose escape wasn't introduced until `NT` to supplement the escape arsenal like `"quoted strings"`. With the `set` syntax, `^` is included in the variablename assigned if the `set` argument is quoted, but not if the original quoteless syntax is used. Best to avoid using `^` unless absolutely necessary IMHO.

Comment: The caret does not need to be quoted to be used in assignment of a variable name. `set "hello^world=ok"` and `set hello^^world=ok` yield the same result. Normal expansion doesn't require escape because it occurs before escape processing, but delayed expansion does require escape. `echo %hello^world%` and `echo !hello^^world!` give the same result. If quoted, then no escape needed: `echo "!hello^world!"`